# Can't get keyboard shortcuts to work for git gutter

Tags: git, vim

I'm using pathogen, so my .vimrc looks like so

```
execute pathogen#infect()

...

nmap <Leader> hu GitGutterRevertHunk
nmap <Leader> hv GitGutterPreviewHunk

nmap <silent> ]h :<C-U>execute v:count1 . "GitGutterNextHunk"<CR>
nmap <silent> [h :<C-U>execute v:count1 . "GitGutterPrevHunk"<CR>
```

I also tried the following from the git gutter site

```
nmap ]h <Plug>GitGutterNextHunk
nmap [h <Plug>GitGutterPrevHunk
nmap <Leader>ha <Plug>GitGutterStageHunk
nmap <Leader>hu <Plug>GitGutterRevertHunk
```

Git gutter itself is working though.  I see diffs update on save.  And the commands all seem to work if I manually type :GitGutterNextHunk :GitGutterRevertHunk

So I'm not sure what's going on, or what steps I should take next to diagnose and get the mappings to work.

Update: ,hu is working.  I just did it accidently.  So it's just [h or [c both don't jump around for me.  Maybe there's a dependency I need?  I use `[{ [( [[` a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am probably late, but this is bug, that has been fixed in 7.4.504

`set langnoremap` fixes this.

Comment: Wish I could install that version :( Oh well...  Thanks!